# The best way to pass a constant to a PHP method with Scope Resolution Operator (::)

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for best way to pass a constant to method of PHP 5.4

I need modify a constant on one class on fly.

Actually I made this:

```
//  Analog::handler(\Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),Analog::<CONSTANT_I_NEED_PASS>>);
switch ($config['debug']) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    Analog::handler(\Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),Analog::CRITICAL);
    break;
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
    Analog::handler(\Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),Analog::NOTICE);
    break;
case 6:
case 7:
    Analog::handler(\Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),Analog::DEBUG);
    break;
```

}

I think there're a best method.

Comment: You can define class constants using const var = 'Value'. To use it within the class methods self::$var

Comment: Analog it's a library. I don't like change or create a fork of this library. I don't understand your solution. Apreciate your time.

Comment: Can u please ellaborate your questions properly

Comment: The whole idea behind a constant is that it is... constant.

Answer (score 2):

A variable constant name can be achieved using [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant):

```
$constantToPass = 'CRITICAL';
Analog::handler(
    \Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),
    constant('\Analog\Handler\File::' . $constantToPass));
```

From PHP 5.5 on you can also use `::class` instead of hard coding the class name and thus make use of namespace resolution:

```
use Analog;

$constantToPass = 'CRITICAL';
Analog::handler(
    Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),
    constant(Analog::class . '::' . $constantToPass));
```

But I would **not** consider this "best method"! It looks like you are trying to remove duplication. What about this approach:

```
switch ($config['debug']) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    $severity = Analog::CRITICAL;
    break;
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
    $severity = Analog::NOTICE;
    break;
case 6:
case 7:
    $severity = Analog::DEBUG;
    break;
}
Analog::handler(
    \Analog\Handler\Threshold::init(\Analog\Handler\File::init($log_file)),
    $severity);
```

Comment: A lot of thanks. I had tried that but I failed. Now after seeing the response I realized that there was a typo. Thanks to you I was able to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify or change constant variables value.You can pass the constant to the method using the self keyword.

```
 self::constant_name;
```